# C# data retrieve from database error

Tags: c#

i have tried to to load the data to text box, while selecting the drop down list, i was created a class for retrieval and called it in drop down list selected index changed. But i cant get the answer what i want. If i have called the class in Button click event it has worked properly. So please correct me. What i made a mistake. This is what my code:

```
public void so()
    {
        con.Open();
        string s2;
        s2 = "select Source from tbl_component where Componetcode='" + Mcodeddl.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand c2 = new SqlCommand(s2, con);
        SqlDataReader d2;
        d2 = c2.ExecuteReader();
        while (d2.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text = d2["Source"].ToString().Trim(); 

        }
        d2.Close();
        con.Close();
    }

//i have called the so class here

 protected void Mcodeddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        so();   
    }
```

Comment: there is a typo in the query Componetcode instaed of *Componentcode*? And then you are subject to query injection

Comment: what's the exception? have u debugged your code?

Comment: error hasn't shown, didn't get what i want exactly

Comment: i have created the field in database in the name of Componetcode, that is what a reason i have given like that

Comment: Is there any data in 'tbl_component' in database against selected Mcodeddl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a breakpoint inside your `Mcodeddl_SelectedIndexChanged` method to see if the event is triggered, also make sure include `AutoPostBack="true"` in your dropdownlist definition

Comment: thanks. I have forgot to check the Auto post back friend. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have specified `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event for the drop down in aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Mcodeddl" runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged= "Mcodeddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Also use [parameterized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) SQL queries.

PS. Your `SO();`  is a method not a class.

Comment: @user1455232, post your part of aspx page containing the dropdownlist

Answer (score 1):

i have got the answer. And i gave the detail what exactly i have did.
         **"Set AutoPostBack=True"**